# Mac Apache 403 error on symlink

Tags: macos, apache

I'm trying to set up directories for some of my php github projects in a separate directory and then create symlinks to them in the web document root.

The document root is /Users/aharris88/sites. I set up a symlink like this:

```
ln -s ~/dropbox/github/tester/ ~/sites/tester
```

For now I have a simple index.php file in it with this code:

```
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
```

but when I go to localhost/~aharris88/tester I get a 403 Forbidden error.
and when I go to localhost/~aharris88 it's not listed with the other directories.

I've gone to /etc/apache2/users and added aharris88.conf with the following:

```
<Directory /Users/aharris88/Sites/>
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I'm using the stock OS X Apache install, but it works when I run mamp instead and go to localhost:8888/tester/.
So how can I make this symlink work with the stock OS X Apache install?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on the stock OS X Apache install, or on MAMP's Apache? If the former, then try stopping MAMP, to make sure that the web server you are using definitely is the MAC OS one.

Comment: I'm trying with the stock OS X Apache install. When it wasn't working, I tried mamp and it worked. But yes, I always stop mamp, when I want to use the stock OS X Apache install and run sudo apachectl start.

Comment: Righto. I'm not particularly au fait with this part of Apache - I don't use user directories. But you might find some clues in this bit of the manual: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html. Have a look at the MAMP httpd.conf to see if there are any relevant directives in there?

Comment: Besides comparing your apache confs, what user is the web server running as in your setup of MAMP vs. OS X? If different (maybe your local user in one and www in another), in Terminal, use sudo to verify that you can access the entire path from `/` all the way to the directory you're trying to serve as the appropriate web user.

Comment: I ran this line of php: <?php echo exec('whoami'); ?> and mamp runs as my local user (aharris88) and apache runs as _www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is based on the comment from @davidr:

I made a php file called whoami.php with the following code:

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

I ran this page with mamp (localhost:888/whoami.php) and then with os x apache install (localhost/~aharris88/whoami.php), since the symlink worked with mamp and not apache.

Mamp returned my local user (aharris88) and apache returned _www. So that meant that _www didn't have access to the directory where the symlink pointed (~/Dropbox/github/tester).

When I checked the permissions, I noticed that the dropbox directory was set to 700 aharris88, so I set it to 755.

```
sudo chmod 755 dropbox
```

and that fixed my issue.

Comment: Thx for pointing out that is the whole dropbox folder that need the chmod 755